# Converting String to Timestamp

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two columns. One which is a UTC timestamp. The second column is the UTC offset formatted as a string. So California is -08:00, and Paris would be 01:00.

How can I combine the two columns to get local time? 
When I try to cast the string to timestamp I get an invalid timestamp due to the negatives.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a string representation of a timestamp into a timestamp using `timestamp()`.

So, this should work:

```
select timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00-08:00') as ca_time,
       timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00+01:00') as paris_time
```

If you want *local* time, you can convert to a `datetime`:

```
select datetime(timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00-08:00'), 'America/New_York') as ca_time,
       datetime(timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00+01:00'), 'America/New_York') as paris_time
```

That said, I would encourage you to convert the strings to `timestamp`s *and leave them there*.  Just convert to local time for output purposes and to determine the local date.  Learning to work with UTC has a bit of a learning curve, but it prevents lots of problems down the road.

Comment: Thank you. However, when i try to convert the offset to a timestamp it produces an error. Is this because of the negatives?

Comment: @poemofxtasy . . . Those two query work when I run them in BigQuery using Standard SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Below example for BigQuery

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.yourtable` AS (
  SELECT '-08:00' timezone_offset, TIMESTAMP '2020-03-01 03:41:27 UTC' UTC_timestamp UNION ALL
  SELECT '01:00',  '2020-03-01 03:41:27 UTC'
)
SELECT * EXCEPT(hour, minute), 
  DATETIME(TIMESTAMP_ADD(TIMESTAMP_ADD(UTC_timestamp, INTERVAL CAST(hour AS INT64) HOUR), INTERVAL CAST(minute AS INT64) MINUTE)) AS local_time
FROM `project.dataset.yourtable`,
UNNEST([STRUCT(SPLIT(timezone_offset, ':')[OFFSET(0)] AS hour, SPLIT(timezone_offset, ':')[OFFSET(1)] AS minute)])
```

with output

```
Row     timezone_offset     UTC_timestamp               local_time   
1       -08:00              2020-03-01 03:41:27 UTC     2020-02-29T19:41:27  
2       01:00               2020-03-01 03:41:27 UTC     2020-03-01T04:41:27
```

Answer (score 0):

What I always do, I use condition to convert the timestamp UTC into local datetime. I check the list of tz name in here.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones.  As long you have utc_offset or region or country name you can change/convert UTC to local timestamp / datetime.

Below the query:

```
#standardSQL
WITH
  sample_data_utc AS (
  SELECT
    TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), SECOND) AS utc_timestamp,
    '01:00' AS utc_offset
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), SECOND) AS utc_timestamp,
    '-08:00' AS utc_offset)
SELECT
  STEP_ONE.utc_timestamp,
  CASE STEP_ONE.utc_offset
    WHEN '01:00'  THEN DATETIME(STEP_ONE.utc_timestamp, "Europe/Paris")
    WHEN '-08:00' THEN DATETIME(STEP_ONE.utc_timestamp, "America/Tijuana")
  --find out the TZ name in here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones
  ELSE
  NULL
END
  AS local_timestamp
FROM
  sample_data_utc AS STEP_ONE
```

with output:

```
Row     utc_timestamp               local_timestamp  
1       2020-03-01 03:41:27 UTC     2020-02-29T19:41:27  
2       2020-03-01 03:41:27 UTC     2020-03-01T04:41:27
```